# How to share React context between _document.js and pages on Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Let's say I have this context:

```
export const ThemeContext = createContext();

export function ThemeWrapper({ children }) {
  const sharedState = {
    darkMode: false,
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={sharedState}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useThemeContext() {
  return useContext(ThemeContext);
}
```

Which I can access on `_document.js` like this:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ThemeWrapper, ThemeContext } from "../context/theme";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static contextType = ThemeContext;
  render() {
    console.log("theme", this.context);
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

class Wrapped extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeWrapper>
        <MyDocument />
      </ThemeWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default Wrapped;
```

Now I also want to access this context from a page:

```
import { useThemeContext } from "../context/theme";

const SomePage = () => {
  const theme = useThemeContext();

  console.log("theme", theme);

  return (
    <div>Hi, I'm a page</div>
  );
};
```

`_document.js` logs out `theme { darkMode: false }` on the Next.js console when the page is first loaded but `SomePage` logs out `theme undefined` on the Chrome console everytime you navigate to it.

Any suggestions?

I need to toggle some class on the `html` tag depending on this context. Trying to [manually toggle dark mode using Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually).

Comment: So is the new page wrapped inside a ThemeWrapper?

Comment: Instead of wrapping the document try wrapping Main in ThemeWrapper.
When you wrap the native document from next, I have a feeling that might not work.

Comment: You can also try creating a custom app and adding your context wrapper there. https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

Comment: You should use the ThemeWrapper in a custom App not Document

Comment: @Keith Nope, do I need to? I thought that wrapping the document would give me access anywhere down the tree.

Comment: @Mellet @nip Thing is I need this context to toggle some classes on the `html` and `body` tags.

Comment: For what purpose are you adding classes to html and body? :)

Comment: For [manually toggling dark mode with Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrapping `_document` with `ThemeWrapper` doesn't give you access to the context inside pages (probably because [it's only rendered in the server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#caveats)), you will need to wrap `_app` for that. Just note that `_document` will not re-render on context state changes.

For this specific use case, an alternative is to use [`next-themes`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-themes).